# Free group and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

suppose $F$ is a free group generated by $x$ and $y$.

1. Prove that $u=x^2, v=y^3$ generates a subgroup of $F$, and it is isomorphic to the free group on $u,v$
2. Prove that $u=x^2, v=y^2, z = xy$ generates a subgroup of $F$, and it is isomorphic to the free group on $u,v,z$

My problem is below:
I think what they want me to prove is the same thing in my mind, because I think, for example in problem 1, the two groups they mentioned are just a same group generated by $u$ and $v$. What should I prove and how?

Comment: For problem one, you are given a subgroup $\langle u,v\rangle\subset F$ and asked to show that $\langle u,v\rangle$ is free. That is, show that $u^{n_1}v^{m_1}\cdots u^{n_k}v^{m_k}=1$ implies $n_i=m_j=0$.

Comment: Oh thanks! Now I can see the point.

Comment: Are two free group isomorphic with the same number (finite) of generators? After I prove $<u,v>$ to be a free group, what should I do?

Comment: Then you should go on for 2.